# Making a screen for Flash CS5

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, flash-cs5

I'm making my own gallery which a a collection of SWFs.
[image]
So far, I've manage to load my swf files in my movieclip, but the problem is that it doesn't look like they are showing in the 'screen' I made.
[image]

Is there any way to use my 'screen' movieclip as a mask?

Code used:

```
button1.onRelease=function(){        
loadMovie("house.swf","screen");        
}
button2.onRelease=function(){        
screen.loadMovie("ninja.swf");      
}
button3.onRelease=function(){        
screen.loadMovie("ball.swf");       
}
button4.onRelease=function(){        
screen.loadMovie("car.swf");        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take one movieclip, and keep instance name as mc inside the screen movieclip, and apply masking for mc movieclip for specific area inside the screen

see below code

```
button1.onRelease=function(){        
loadMovie("house.swf",screen.mc);        
}
button2.onRelease=function(){        
screen.mc.loadMovie("ninja.swf");      
}
```

or

use `setMask()` function

[Read More](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001353.html)